# Formatting Date text for FFPojoHelper writing to a file

Tags: java, file-io

When I use a `Date` object and write it to a file using `FFPojoHelper` it gets printed as `2112013` which mean `21 Jan 2013`. I would like to write to the file as `01/21/2013`

```
FFPojoHelper ffpojo = FFPojoHelper.getInstance();
        for(MyClass DataLine != null) {
            String dataLine= ffpojo.parseToText(DataLine[i]);
            textFileWriter.write(dataLine);
            textFileWriter.newLine();
        }
```

docs https://github.com/ffpojo/ffpojo

Comment: what is the type of `DataLine`?

Comment: just a class i use to store various other attributes

Comment: I couldn't find any javadoc to this API (i guess this is yet another case of `the code itself is the doc`). I would suggest [download the sources](https://github.com/ffpojo/ffpojo/tree/master/ffpojo) and debug it.

Comment: https://github.com/ffpojo/ffpojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using DateDecorator? See if this sample helps:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.ffpojo/ffpojo-samples/1.0/com/github/ffpojo/samples/PositionalRecordParsingWithDecoratorExample.java#PositionalRecordParsingWithDecoratorExample.DateDecorator